# Is it possible to make a variable a reference to a class attribute in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, methods, attributes

I want to use a class method that determine which attribute to modify based on the method argument. Here's a very simple analogous version:

```
class Data:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 1

    def increment(self, a_or_b):

        variable = {'a': self.a, 'b': self.b}[a_or_b]
        variable += 1

d1 = Data()
d1.increment(a_or_b='a')
print(d1.a)
```

I want `d1.a` to equal 2, but it equals 1 because the class attribute hasn't actually been modified, just the variable `variable`. I could instead define increment as:

```
def increment(self, a_or_b): 
    if a_or_b is 'a': 
        self.a += 1
    else: 
        self.b += 1
```

But this feels cumbersome, especially if I want the entire alphabet and not just the first two letters. Is there a way to instead make `variable` a reference to either `self.a` or `self.b` such that the attribute gets modified?

Comment: This would work, if `variable` referenced a mutable object. But it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You probably shouldn't do this but here's an option.

```
class Data:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 1

    def increment(self, a_or_b):
        if hasattr(self, a_or_b):
            setattr(self, a_or_b, getattr(self, a_or_b) + 1)


d1 = Data()
d1.increment('a')
print(d1.a)
```

This is manipulating the `hasattr`, `setattr`, and `getattr` builtins.

`hasattr` takes 2 arguments. The object, which is passed in with `self`, and the attribute name as a string.

`getattr` takes the same 2 arguments.

`setattr` takes one additional argument. The value you wish to set to it.

Comment: `setattr` seems like a feasible workaround. Unfortunately in my actual usage `a` and `b` are `pandas.DataFrame`s and I'm also setting values to those DataFrames and calling additional methods on them. So I'd need to `setattr` before each call to other methods in this case, which is why I'm looking for another way of directly modifying the attributes

Answer (score 1):

If you have an entire alphabet, then 26 (give or take) individual attributes is the wrong approach. Use a `dict`.

```
class Data:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = dict.fromkey("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 1)

    def incrementself, c):
        self.data[c] += 1
```